# How do I use update_or_create In django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have problem on using update_or_create method in django I have following model

```py
class Search(BaseModel):
    booking_id = models.IntegerField(db_index=True, unique=True)
    trip_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=trip_choice)
    flight_date = models.DateField()
    return_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

And I tried creating if not exists or update existing value but I am getting integrity error:

```
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "flight_search_booking_id_key" DETAIL:  Key (booking_id)=(4) already exists.
```

Here is how I tried saving.

```py
def _save_to_db(self):
    # 14. check if booking id exists previously if exists raise error
    defaults = {'booking_id': 4}

    flight_data, _created = Search.objects.update_or_create(
        booking_id=self._flight_data.get('booking_id'),
        trip_type=self._query_params.get('flight_type'),
        flight_date=self._query_params.get('departure_date'),
        defaults=defaults
    )
    flight_data.save()
```

I learned default should be provided so I did that too but I am getting error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intent is to update the booking with `booking_id == 4`, then I think this is the correct approach:

```
def _save_to_db(self):
        # 14. check if booking id exists previously if exists raise error
        defaults = {
            'trip_type': self._query_params.get('flight_type'), 
            'flight_date': self._query_params.get('departure_date'),
            'booking_id': 4,
        }

        flight_data, _created = Search.objects.update_or_create(
            booking_id=self._flight_data.get('booking_id'),
            defaults=defaults
        )
        flight_data.save()
```

That will update the values of trip_type and flight_date in the `Search` object with `booking_id=4`, or create such a `Search` object otherwise.

Take a look at the django documentation which specifies what the approximate equivalent code is that doesn't use update_or_create: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.update_or_create

Comment: So I am actually trying to understand what is default actually?

Comment: @daneilJames The defaults argument is a dictionary containing the values to be used to update the the object if it exists, or to create it if it doesn't.  All the other keyword arguments are used to search for the object.

Comment: As usual the django documentation words this excellently: "The update_or_create method tries to fetch an object from database based on the given kwargs. If a match is found, it updates the fields passed in the defaults dictionary."

Comment: so does that mean If all changing value that sent in my code like flight_date, trip_type need to be included in defaults?

Comment: Yes I believe so

Answer (score 1):

```
   def _save_to_db(self):
        # 14. check if booking id exists previously if exists raise error
        defaults = {'booking_id': 4}

        flight_data, _created = Search.objects.update_or_create(
            booking_id=self._flight_data.get('booking_id',defaults.get("booking_id")),
            trip_type=self._query_params.get('flight_type'),
            flight_date=self._query_params.get('departure_date')
        )
        flight_data.save()
```

Try it.

Comment: This will result in the `booking_id` keyword argument being specified twice which is a SyntaxError